# Starting selenium program in a manually opened browser

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

I am using selenium and python in order to scrape data on a website.
The problem is I need to manually log in because there is a CAPTCHA after the login.
My question is the following : is there a way to start the program on a page that is already loaded ? (for example, here I would log to the website, solve the CAPTCHA manually, and then launch the program that would scrape the data)

Note: I have already been looking for an answer on SO but did not find it, might have missed it as it seems to be an obvious question.

Comment: I hope my answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't open in headless mode. open in head mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time 

options = Options()
options.headless = False # Set false here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")
time.sleep(30) # wait 30 seconds, this should give enough time to manually do the capture
# do other code here
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if I understand correctly, what you say is I have to log in during the **time.sleep(30)** and then if I put the code I need to execute in the **#do other code here**, and that should work?

Comment: @Odhian 100% correct, yes. adjust time as needed.